# How to create dependent custom options

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to create dependent custom options with each custom option, where after clicking on the button, it will open popup and drop-down options and their values will be available to add, excluding current option and its values! I have created popup and options there. I did this from custom options provider file, and the component file is added to create options, but now I want to exclude current option from dropdown.